# Trying to Scrape a website for data but getting an Error 403

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.csgoanalyst.win'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
page_soup.body
```

I am trying to scrape hltv.org in order to find out what maps each team bans and picks. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
>>> page_html = uClient.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'uClient' is not defined
>>> uClient.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'uClient' is not defined
```

I tried the script on another website so I know it works. I assume hltv has blocked bots or whatever from doing this and I know I shouldn't particularly be doing it if they don't want people to but I would love to get the data.

Any help will be super helpful. 
Thank you.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403. You may be able to get around this by using the `requests` package, instead of `urllib`, so you can set the request's headers.

Comment: If you insist on `urllib` use: `uReq(Request(my_url, headers=headers))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/maps/6665/Astralis'

u_client = uReq(my_url)

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(u_client,"html.parser")

print soup
```

and if you want to remove the tags

```
import bleach

print bleach.clean(soup,tags = [],strip = True)
```

Comment: yes you should use request.Because the website is forbidden and to be honest its just simple as urllib

Comment: i tried that but got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bs' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `requests` module instead of `urllib`. It's fast, and has other advantages as well. You're getting forbidden because you're lacking a `User-Agent` header. Try something like the following:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}
my_url = 'https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/maps/6665/Astralis'

page = requests.get(my_url, headers=headers)
page_html = page.text
```

`requests` can be easily installed using `pip`: `pip install requests`

You can add headers using `urllib` as well, but it's slightly more complex syntactically and perhaps slower.

Comment: thank you, does page.text do the same thing as uClient.read() ?

Comment: @Rory Welcome and yes, `text` does the same job. But it's an attribute as opposed to a method, i.e, the text is already stored in `page.text`. Is my code working for you?

Comment: yes, the code seems to work. however, when I try to do the next bit my method isn't working. this is the full code that I am working with 

EDIT: the code looks a bit messy in here, so I have updated the main post with it.

Comment: @Rory Well what's the problem?

Comment: i think I sorted the issue out. thanks for the help. i changed it to this: `import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://arcanebet.com/sportxml?days=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
print(soup.prettify())`